# Render raw HTML inside a react div

Tags: html, reactjs

I have this raw HTML that is stored in the database and I'm trying to render it inside a div.

```
const style = {
    border: '2px solid #eee',
    height: '270px',
    width: '100%',
    overflow: 'auto',
    padding: '10px'
}

const test = () => {
   const [contentFromDB, setContentFromDB] = useState("");

   useEffect(() => {
       async function fetchData() {
          setContentFromDB(await myAPI.getData())
       }
   }, []);

   return (
      <>
        <div className="row">
           <h3>Test Render</h3>
           <div style={style}>
              {contentFromDB}
           </div>
        </div>
      </>
   )
}

export default test;
```

The problem is that it is keeping all the HTML tags, it is rendering as a string (image below). Is there a way to render the raw HTML inside my div?

[image]

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to achieve this.

```
const style = {
    border: '2px solid #eee',
    height: '270px',
    width: '100%',
    overflow: 'auto',
    padding: '10px'
}

const test = () => {
   const [contentFromDB, setContentFromDB] = useState("");

   useEffect(() => {
       async function fetchData() {
          setContentFromDB(await myAPI.getData())
       }
   }, []);

   return (
      <>
        <div className="row">
           <h3>Test Render</h3>
           <div style={style}>
              <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:contentFromDB}} />
           </div>
        </div>
      </>
   )
}

export default test;
```

Comment: also see this link -> https://tr.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: Thank you. It was what I was looking for!